# Почему нормально не обрезает substring

Tags: c#

У меня есть такая штука, из нее нужно вытащить ссылку(murl), т.к я плохо знаю Regex, я пытаюсь сделать это substring, но он почему-то отказывается нормально работать

```
{
  "cid":"9TEtVjY3",
  "purl":"https://www.pinterest.co.uk/pin/338966309457499894/",
  "murl":"https://i.pinimg.com/originals/32/c3/32/32c332d62177e9faa7d1af61add2c8e7.png",
  "turl":"https://tse4.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.9TEtVjY3K2QPrfljHO6bGwHaK-&pid=15.1",
  "md5":"f5312d5636372b640fadf9631cee9b1b",
  "shkey":"LHCQWHfLcNQK09Pqm6Xt6wKJoCsFkSuv1ItYLzJe3oQ=",
  "t":"Студия Paramount Pictures опубликовала новый постер и ...",
  "mid":"6BA877CB86A1E3E672FDD4D00011DA44D08637A3",
  "desc":""
}
```

```
link_picture = link_picture.Substring(link_picture.IndexOf("murl\":\""), link_picture.IndexOf("murl\":\"")-(link_picture.IndexOf("\",\""))).Replace("murl\":\"","");
```

Comment: Зачем вам тут `Substring`...? Это JSON, так работайте с им как подобает!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
public class MurMurl
{
    string cid { get; set; }
    string purl{ get; set; }
    string murl { get; set; }
    string turl { get; set; }
    string md5 { get; set; }
    string shkey { get; set; }
    string t { get; set; }
    string mid { get; set; }
    string desc { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
var item = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MurMurl>(link_picture);
string murl = item.murl;
```