# C# десериализация json

Tags: c#, json, десериализация

Имеется ответ от сервера:

```
    {
  "entries" : [ {
    "id" : 100038,
    "version" : 3,
    "contractPrice" : 96600.00,
    "contractStatus" : "ON_EXECUTION",
    "uisPublicationStatus" : null,
    "modificationReasonTypes" : [ ],
    "signDate" : "2017-04-11T21:00:00Z",
    "easuzNumber" : "184793-17",
    "uisNumber" : null,
    "number" : "АХС-2017/020",
    "created" : null,
    "link" : "http://easuz.mosreg.ru/easuz2/#/Contract?id=4325440",
    "orphanageReasonTypes" : [ ],
    "notPublishedInUis" : false,
    "contractSubject" : "Поставка оборудования для выполнения строительно-монтажных работ по установке прибора учета холодной воды в нежилом помещении, расположенном по адресу: МО, г.Шатура, ул.Большевик, д.167",
    "customerName" : "Государственное бюджетное учреждение Московской области \"Мосавтодор\"",
    "customerInn" : "5000001525",
    "customerKpp" : "502401001",
    "businessUnitIds" : [ 1, 1050 ],
    "supplierName" : "Общество с ограниченной ответственностью \"ПроектТрансГаз\"",
    "supplierCompanyId" : null,
    "supplierInn" : "7717763383",
    "supplierOgrn" : null,
    "supplierKpp" : "771701001",
    "supplierStarStatus" : null,
    "positionId" : 100639,
    "positionNumber" : "314243-17",
    "positionTenderPlanId" : 100005,
    "purchaseType" : "FL44",
    "contractExecutionOnly" : false,
    "customerCompanyId" : 100002,
    "actualExecutionScheduleId" : null,
    "executionScheduleWaitingForContractExecutionCompletion" : null,
    "executionScheduleRequiresChanges" : null,
    "positionPermissions" : {
      "editAccessGroupAssignments" : false,
      "viewTenderPlanPositionHistory" : true,
      "editTenderPlanPositionAfterPlacement" : true,
      "manageTenderPlanPosition" : true,
      "registryExecutionSchedulesForTenderPlanPosition" : true,
      "createContractTermsForTenderPlanPosition" : true,
      "createExecutionScheduleForTenderPlanPosition" : true,
      "placeTenderPlanPosition" : false,
      "viewTenderPlanPosition" : true,
      "registryContractTermsForTenderPlanPosition" : true
    },
    "executionSchedulePermissions" : null,
    "factPrice" : null,
    "subContractorDecisions" : null,
    "hasChildren" : false,
    "vatSumCalcByCustomer" : 0,
    "wayToSpecifyContractPrice" : null,
    "maxReductionAmountInPercent" : null,
    "maxExcessAmountInPercent" : null,
    "pricePolicy" : null,
    "nationalProjectNames" : null,
    "toContractSideRole" : null
  } ],
  "totalCount" : 1,
  "pageMode" : "ENTRIES_AND_TOTAL",
  "meta" : {
    "updated" : { },
    "deleted" : { },
    "inserted" : { },
    "rootType" : "CONTRACT",
    "timestamp" : 1624284413978
  }
}
```

переменная, которая получает данный ответ:

```
string supplierInfo = Request.Post(supplierRequest, accessToken, postdata_sup, "application/json");
```

необходимо получить к примеру "supplierName", подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу это сделать

Comment: А искать конечно лень, да? Прям вон, сверху строка поиска, пишете `[c#] json` и сразу видите то, что вам надо...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ предложение то же :) до 5 ссылок можно воткнуть в голубую плашку.

Comment: @aepot Ну есть уже эталонные две закрывашки, [одна](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/736927/220553) и на 2-ю уже закрыли дублем. Этот кстати вопрос тоже [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1297259/220553), почему Вы там ответили я без понятия...